# How to prevent to change value DateTime object from Utc time zone to WebApplication user timezone in Kendo-UI MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm facing one issue in my MVC application. In one module I'm using `kendo-ui grid` (Ex. `@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model))`). Issue is, its change the `DateTime` object value when it render on the web browser. Ex. If my `DateTime`object value on server side is `'2016-09-20 00:00:00'` and when it renders on the browser then this value becomes `'2016-09-20 05:30:00'` (India time zone +5:30), on client side rendering `DateTime` object value add the time zone value of the user's browser. so my `DateTime` object value is changed and I do not want to change it. Is there any solution available for this kind of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date values are changed by the **browser**, because JavaScript Date objects are represented in the local time zone. The workaround is to use UTC:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/how-to/utc-time-on-both-server-and-client